# Get nginx to reload with backup upstream when there are no active upstreams

Tags: nginx

is it possible to reload nginx when there are no active upstreams present, in other words, if there is no active upstream, nginx should route calls to backup upstreams automatically.

Normal config ->

```
upstream myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    server 127.0.0.1:8002 backup;    
    server 127.0.0.1:8003 backup;
}
```

I want to be able to reload nginx on something like ->

```
upstream myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:8002 backup;    
    server 127.0.0.1:8003 backup;
}
```

Currently, nginx throws error by saying no upstream address found in the above upstream block.

Updated -
I want to make nginx intelligent. Say, 8000/8001 ports are in one dc and 8002/8003 ports are in second dc. If first dc boxes are not available, nginx should automatically route traffic to the second dc

Answer (score 0):

The **backup** flag indicates that it should be used when the primary is not sending the response, from the [official upstream module documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server):

> Backup: Marks the server as a backup server. It will be passed
>   requests when the primary servers are unavailable.

Simply remove the **backup**  flag from the first server, otherwise you are not defining a *primary server*.

```
upstream myproject {
    server 127.0.0.1:8002;    
    server 127.0.0.1:8003 backup;
}
```

Out of curiosity, why would you leave both as backup? What are you trying to accomplish, load balacing or failover capacity?

Comment: I'm betting on insufficiently intelligent automation.

Comment: updated the description